# Get chrome user profile information

Tags: google-chrome

**Goal**

To be able to programmatically obtain the chrome profile display name, as well as the image associated with them.

**Question**

Where within the chrome user data directory

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile X
```

Would I be able to find the information I am seeking?

- To elaborate, the following image illustrates what data I am referring to

[image]

> Profile 1 Image: Bike Name: Leisure
>
> Profile 2 Image: empty Name: Empty
>
> ...

Comment: [Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) might be helpful to you.